# Why does a successful merge break my code?

Tags: git, xcode4

When using XCode4 I created a new branch and implemented a very small method on this new branch. I saw that the branch was working properly so I made a commit on this new branch and then switched back to my main branch. I merged the two branches together (the new one into my main branch). Now my project is not working.

The exact same thing happened yesterday. I never found the problem so I started over from the beginning on this current project. What is causing this?

Comment: Just because there are no merge conflicts, it doesn't mean that your project will build successfully. Git has no way of knowing whether your changes are actually compatible or not. You'll have to show us some information for us to be able to figure out what's causing the error.

Comment: @hammar - I think we need a name for this concept, I've seen it a lot lately.  Maybe "merge dazzling", because it's easy to get dazzled by the powerful new merge functionality and forget that humans are still the only ones who can check that code is correct (unless you write Agda...)

Comment: I was wondering the same thing. Why doesn’t anyone mention this in books and tutorials for Git? Merging two separate branches has the potential to break the code. We need to test if it isn’t a fast-forward and debug if required.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where you started your development branch:

- if that was from `HEAD` of `main` branch, then the merge back into `main` should have been a fast-forward one (i.e. `main HEAD` should have simply be moved at `dev HEAD`), and your project should have worked.
- if that was from any commit *before* `main HEAD` (i.e. if `main HEAD` has moved during `dev` branch development), then the merge isn't a fast forward one, and you are combining (automatically if the changes in both branches are separate) two different sets of changes.
  Then the result needs to be tested and validated again.